# iMessage from iPad wont send to texts to my husband, but I can send them to other iphone users without issues

Tags: messages

Recently, without any settings changes, my iMessage on iPad began failing every attempt I made to message my husband.  I can still message other friends from my iPad without any other issues.  I can still message my husband from my iPhone.  So frustrated....looked at settings options and can not detect anything to fix this issue.  I have restarted iPad several times, still not working.

Comment: are you sure you're sending it to the same email or phone number as from your iPhone?

Comment: Are you sure he didn't disable iMessage on his device?

Comment: Rob, he can get my iMessages from my iphone to his iphone just fine.

Comment: Kevin, it appears to be the same phone number. It used to work and suddenly stopped.  I deleted his contact information and it deleted it from both devices.  I reinstalled his contact information, but still with the same results.